# How does/should global data in modules across packages be managed in Python/other languages?

Tags: python, namespaces, module, language-design, package

I am trying to design the package and module system for a programming language ([Heron](http://heron-language.googlecode.com)) which can be both compiled and interpreted, and from what I have seen I really like the Python approach. Python has a rich choice of modules, which seems to contribute largely to its success.

What I don`t know is what happens in Python if a module is included in two different compiled packages: are there separate copies made of the data or is it shared?

Related to this are a bunch of side-questions:

1. Am I right in assuming that packages can be compiled in Python?
2. What are there pros and cons to the two approaches (copying or sharing of module data)?
3. Are there widely known problems with the Python module system, from the point of view of the Python community? For example is there a PEP under consideration for enhancing modules/packages?
4. Are there certain aspects of the Python module/package system which wouldn`t work well for a compiled language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you asked a lot of questions.  Here are some hints to get a bit further:

1. a.   Python code is lexed and compiled into Python specific instructions, but not compiled to machine executable code.  The ".pyc" file is automatically created whenever you run python code that does not match the existing .pyc timestamp.  This feature can be turned off.   You might play with the dis module to see these instructions.
    b.  When a module is imported, it is executed (top to bottom) in its own namespace and that namespace cached globally.   When you import from another module, the module is not executed again.  Remember that def is just a statement.  You may want to put a print('compiling this module') statement in your code to trace it.
2. It depends.
3. There were recent enhancements, mostly around specifying which module needed to be loaded.  Modules can have relative paths so that a huge project might have multiple modules with the a same name.
4. Python itself won't work for a compiled language.  Google for "unladen swallow blog" to see the tribulations of trying to speed up a language where "a = sum(b)" can change meanings between executions.  Outside of corner cases, the module system forms a nice bridge between source code and a compiled library system.  The approach works well, and Python's easy wrapping of C code (swig, etc.) helps.

Comment: Lots of helpful answers, but this one really hit it home for me. Short and to the point. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Modules are the only truly global objects in Python, with all other global data based around the module system (which uses sys.modules as a registry).  Packages are simply modules with special semantics for importing submodules.  "Compiling" a .py file into a .pyc or .pyo isn't compilation as understood for most languages: it only checks the syntax and creates a code object which, when executed in the interpreter, creates the module object.

example.py:

```
print "Creating %s module." % __name__

def show_def(f):
  print "Creating function %s.%s." % (__name__, f.__name__)
  return f

@show_def
def a():
  print "called: %s.a" % __name__
```

Interactive session:

```
>>> import example
# first sys.modules['example'] is checked
# since it doesn't exist, example.py is found and "compiled" to example.pyc
# (since example.pyc doesn't exist, same would happen if it was outdated, etc.)
Creating example module. # module code is executed
Creating function example.a. # def statement executed
>>> example.a()
called: example.a
>>> import example
# sys.modules['example'] found, local variable example assigned to that object
# no 'Creating ..' output
>>> d = {"__name__": "fake"}
>>> exec open("example.py") in d
# the first import in this session is very similar to this
# in that it creates a module object (which has a __dict__), initializes a few
# variables in it (__builtins__, __name__, and others---packages' __init__
# modules have their own as well---look at some_module.__dict__.keys() or
# dir(some_module))
# and executes the code from example.py in this dict (or the code object stored
# in example.pyc, etc.)
Creating fake module. # module code is executed
Creating function fake.a. # def statement executed
>>> d.keys()
['__builtins__', '__name__', 'a', 'show_def']
>>> d['a']()
called: fake.a
```

Your questions:

1. They are compiled, in a sense, but not as you would expect if you're familiar with how C compilers work.
2. If the data is immutable, copying is feasible, and should be indistinguishable from sharing except for object identity (`is` operator and `id()` in Python).
3. Imports may or may not execute code (they always assign a local variable to an object, but that poses no problems) and may or may not modify sys.modules.  You must be careful to not import in threads, and generally it is best to do all imports at the top of every module: this leads to a cascading graph so all the imports are done at once and then __main__ continues and does the Real Work™.

   - I don't know of any current PEP, but there's already a lot of complex machinery in place, too.  For example packages can have a [__path__ attribute](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#index-1048) (really a list of paths) so submodules don't have to be in the same directory, and these paths can even be computed at runtime!  (Example mungepath package below.)  You can have your own import hooks, use import statements inside functions, directly call __import__, and I wouldn't be surprised to find 2-3 other unique ways to work with packages and modules.
4. A subset of the import system would work in a traditionally-compiled language, as long as it was similar to something like C's #include.  You could run the "first level" of execution (creating the module objects) in the compiler, and compile those results.  There are significant drawbacks to this, however, and amounts to separate execution contexts for module-level code and functions executed at runtime (and some functions would have to run in both contexts!).  (Remember in Python that every statement is executed at runtime, even def and class statements.)

   - I believe this is the main reason traditionally-compiled languages restrict "top-level" code to class, function, and object declarations, eliminating this second context.  Even then, you have initialization problems for global objects in C/C++ (and others), unless managed carefully.

mungepath/__init__.py:

```
print __path__
__path__.append(".") # CWD, would be different in non-example code
print __path__
from . import example # this is example.py from above, and is NOT in mungepath/
# note that this is a degenerate case, in that we now have two names for the
# 'same' module: example and mungepath.example, but they're really different
# modules with different functions (use 'is' or 'id()' to verify)
```

Interactive session:

```
>>> import example
Creating example module.
Creating function example.a.
>>> example.__dict__.keys()
['a', '__builtins__', '__file__', 'show_def', '__package__',
 '__name__', '__doc__']
>>> import mungepath
['mungepath']
['mungepath', '.']
Creating mungepath.example module.
Creating function mungepath.example.a.
>>> mungepath.example.a()
called: mungepath.example.a
>>> example is mungepath.example
False
>>> example.a is mungepath.example.a
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Global data is scoped at the interpreter level.

1. "packages" can be compiled as a package is just a collection of modules which themselves can be compiled.
2. I am not sure I understand given the established scoping of data.